# How do I set all of my apps to Vibrate but my calls to Sound in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, notifications

I have tried to do this by hand, but it just doesn't work and shuts off all notifs. Additionally, there are apps like WhatsApp which just don't have a Vibrate setting. Is there a systematic way to do that?